Can sound stop a bullet?
Can sound stop bullets? I am working on a near future game and am trying to find a reason that guns would be rarely used on the battlefield. Aside from the noise breaking your eardrums, could sound be used to directly stop a bullet, or be used as some sort of shield? If not other ways of producing this kind of effect are welcome.

(1) Infantry shooting bullets at infantry went out of fashion in the 1960s. Man-portable firearms already are a bad option for combat when we have tanks and unmanned aerial vehicles and smart bombs and cannon and cruise missiles. (2) The only army ever which used swords as the main weapon in combat was the Roman army, and even the Roman army switched to using spears as the main combat weapon at some point in the 4th century, 1,700 years ago. (3) Which means that in order for swords to become the main combat weapon, you need to get rid not only of guns, but also of horses and common sense.

You are of course aware of S. M. Stirling's 15 (!) volume series of the Emberverse? Long story short, engines and firearms and electricity don't work. Nobody knows why they don't work, but they don't, and everybody has to deal with it.

We are not a brainstorming site. Questions asking for an open ended list of ideas are not permitted here. Come up with a reason on your own and ask us for help resolving any specific worldbuilding problems you may have with it. This subject has also been asked numerous times before on this site. Before asking please search to see if a similar question addresses your problem, otherwise your question is likely to be closed as a duplicate.

Additionally if you want shields that deflect bullets in your world, you just need to say that they exist in your world. You are the only person who ultimately can decide what is and isn't possible in your world. Please remember that we require questions on this site to be focused. A question asking if magnetic shielding can deflect bullets should not be in the same post as one where you're asking us to generate ideas for you.

Question is ill-phrased for the site, so I won't answer and encourage you to look at the tour - which will give you a better understanding of how to frame your question. Now that my civic duty is done, I must abscond and forget to mention the Holtzman shield which is Herbert's excuse to have (mostly) swords instead of guns.

Question: How drastically do you want to change the world? Things like having significant higher air pressure or low-levels of flammable gas everywhere - but those have far greater world building implications.

"What are some resons I can use for guns not working in my story?" - Err, before they published, they forgot to proofread the instruction manuals?

versions of this question have been asked several times why do none of them answer your question?

Hi Oog! So, probably the single best method for asking questions anywhere on SE, & especially here in WB.SE, is to write a question about a focused and specific worldbuilding problem.  As you can see, your query is in the queue headed for closure. This isn't a bad thing, but it does mean that the community finds one or more issues are plaguing your question, making it a poor fit for this forum. It's generally a good idea to do a little in house research first: just see if anyone else has asked a (cont)

(cont) similar question before. Some questions, such as this one, are actually surprisingly popular! If we've done our job well, you may not even have to ask your own question, because it'll already have an answer! If you still think that none of those other questions really fit what you're looking for, then you'll want to reduce your question to a simple problem. Something focused. Beginning a query with "what are some reasons..." is a sure fire (cont)

(cont) way to get your question closed for not being focused! We call this an "infinite list of things" or a "discussion" type question. This won't work anywhere on SE. What I would suggest is alter your marquee question to Will THIS reason for guns not working work... This will narrow the focus of your question very nicely. Then, tell us a little about your world. Go with environmental hazard or lack of materials! Nail something down! Then, use that final paragraph to give us the full question: Given the above, will this kind of magnetic forcefield... Finally, you'll want (cont)

(cont) to write out some parameters by which you'll judge a solid answer. As you can see from the (highly downvoted) responses you've got, a lot of people are into murder. Your focus is warfare. So, you'll want to specify that a good answer will focus on combat in some way.

I’m voting to close this question because the question of how to avoid guns has been asked over and over on this site. Add to that the problem that you're not looking for a worldbuilding rule, but a story foil (see [help/on-topic], we do not help people write their stories) and this is a no-go. The fundamental problem is that because you're not trying to solve a specific problem, all answers are equally valid and opinion based (prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]).

Please let me know if there is a different method of asking questions that is preferred on this site. Carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], and [ask]. That's 95% of the rules. Though a bit outdated, this summary can help. Finally, as a basic rule, if you're here to brainstorm ideas, you're in the wrong place. You can ask anything you want in [chat] (e.g., The Factory Floor) but here on Main you're required to follow Stack Exchange's rules and our policies.

Not in real life, but you're making a game, not a prediction about real life military technology. If you want a game about spearmen and mechs and sword-a-copters, you can just make one. If you want a justification for why there aren't guns, you can have a character ask "Hey, where can I get some guns?" and another character say "Guns don't work on the modern battlefield. It has something to do with sonic waves... or maybe it was electrolytes..."

Hey, @OogTheDestroyer, I notice that you ripped up and rewrote your entire question. The only reason you got away with that is because a bunch of us deleted the low quality answers that were piling up from your first attempt. That's a really rare event. Had a single answer remained, you would have hit our policy of you can't edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. Sometimes (most of the time, probably always) it's better to delete (if you can) or abandon a question and start over rather than try to reuse the same piece of paper.

To enhance @L.Dutch's answer a bit...
A wave of the sea can be large enough and fast enough to destroy ships. Thus, theoretically, a sound wave could be dense enough and broad enough to theoretically stop a bullet, but like ripples in a pond, such a sound wave would have catastrophic consequences.

The bullet might be stopped, but the bodies of the dead would be found for months and the number of the deafened would be countless. Sound doesn't stay in one place and no matter how narrow the original focus it will broaden, reflect, refract... it'll go all over the place (including back at the sender). Ever wondered why you can hear yourself? Some of it is sound carrying through the bone. Some of it is sound carried through the atmosphere to your ears. And echos would definitely be a bad thing.

And you just might hear the sound a few days later after it's rounded the entire Earth. The strength of the sound wave we're considering is awesome. And it'll leave behind a lengthy line of fallen trees, ripped up shrubbery, thrown cars, crushed buildings... we're way, way, way, way, way beyond hurricane strength.

Sound is simply a compressed amount of atmosphere moving through space until it hits an ear drum. Thus, you're just about (if not factually) compressing enough air to liquefy or even solidify it. Neither will transmit through the atmosphere — but let's ignore that and assume that a high enough density just short of liquification can do the trick. (I'm not even going to try to do the math, this is a pretty preposterous idea, but so are lightsabers and Lucas' bank account kinda proves my opinion irrelevant.)

The event creating that strong a sound wave is either going to create a whomping vacuum at the point of transmission or it's going to create a hurricane of in-rushing air to create the wave. More consequences!


Call it a tsunami of sound... a rather impractical and unbelievable solution — but that shouldn't stop a worldbuilder. I rather enjoy watching Marvel Cinematic Universe movies, don't you?
But before we go, let's talk about worldbuilding
I'd like to point out that you're not really asking a worldbuilding question. Per the Help Center, we help people build imaginary worlds. Thus, on your imaginary world sound waves can stop bullets and the question you should have asked was "on my world sound waves can stop bullets, what Real World conditions can I use to rationalize that fact?" Or maybe, "on my world a sound wave can stop a bullet. Ignoring the implausibility of the solution, what kind of damage would such a wave do to brick building?" In other words, you should have been asking about your rule, not whether or not the idea is possible in the Real World. As it is, what you've done is ask us to give you a lesson in physics (not really our job, more the job of Physics.SE) and then tell you no, it's not possible.
(Either way, it would help a lot if you used the Sandbox for a while. Even my first suggested question has problems with this Stack's rules.)
When it comes to being "realistic" (I'm not a fan), you need to be careful what you ask for. The Real World has already been built and if you want to know whether or not things can exist in the Real World the way to find out is through either a library, a science-centered Stack or an education. Not here.
Remember, imaginary worlds. That's what we focus on. In your imaginary world anything is possible and the rules of the Real World only apply when you need a constraint.  Cheers.

Can we add link to this answer to the Vote To Close descriptions? It’s a perfect explanation of “not about worldbuilding” option! Well said!

Sound cannot stop a bullet, the same way as waves in the sea do not stop a ship traveling through them. Sound is made by alternating areas of high pressure and low pressure, while to have a net effect on a bullet you would need to have a constant overpressure ahead of it. And even with that the stopping power would be not that much, considering that a bullet is designed to travel in air as much as possible.
The only way to stop a bullet quickly would be to increase the density of the gas by at least 3 orders of magnitude: water stops a bullet way faster than air.

While you couldn't classify this as sound, I'm curious to know if a shock wave of sufficient pressure could stop or deflect a bullet, and what pressure that would be? At that point you are probably trying to stop a bullet with an explosion.

@GregBurghardt, for that to work, the mass of air hitting the bullet would have to be a substantial fraction of the mass of the bullet. You're either killing everything nearby or doing the equivalent of hitting a bullet with another bullet.

My thoughts:
There are some potential ways you could possibly use Sound to counteract bullets.
Option 1: Resonance frequency of the Bullet.
This will require a lot of handwaivium and is possibly going to irritate a few physicists... But assuming you knew what the right frequency was for either the lead core or the copper jacket, a targetted beam of sound (IIRC - there are some Ultrasonic and Laser-y things that create a very focused beam of sound) - this protects the wearer and the people around it from overpressure.
But in short - you would have something like The Trophy Active Protection system that would:

Detect an incoming round
aim a high-energy sound wave at it
Shatter the bullet
hopefully do this far enough away from the target that they wont get hit by bullet fragments

Things that would aid this solution - most rounds are spinning due to rifling, which means that only a little bit of internal stress would be needed to make the round fly apart, and the spin would direct the majority of the fragments outwards, hopefully small enough that the loose the majority of their kinetic energy.
Of course, you would need some system to quickly rotate frequencies to find the resonant frequency in milliseconds - maybe some combination of a Laser and other stuff.
Option 2: High pressure wind pulse from Sound.
So, looking online - for a .308 round, shooting in wind, the figures I got were 4.3 inches worth of drift for a 50 mph wind at 100 yards. So, approximately .4 inches at 1 yard. The same source indicates that for a 25 moh wind, the deflection is 2.2 inches - so for the sake of simple maths, I am assuming a linear relationship.
Like the other solution we would need a way to detect the incoming round, but unlike the other one - what we would need to know is its estimated point of impact.
We are not going for stopping the bullet, we are going for deflecting the bullet. Average adult male is 18 inches wide, which means in a 1 yard distance, we need to deflect the bullet by at most, 9 inches (hehe). 9/0.4 * 50 = 1,125 Mph wind to push the bullet off course.
I am sure that someone somewhere will be able to do the Maths as to how loud in terms of Decibels that would need to be to have a pressure wave that induced a wind of that speed. I am also sure that such a pressure wave would probably do a number on any living thing nearby.
But there you go - two options using sound that sound plausible enough.

the biggest issue is bullets come in different materials, not just copper and lead, so you wold need many frequencies, and worse becasue the bullet is traveling the frequency changes on where the bullet is relative to the source so you need an AI that can estimate the velocity and dirrection and calculate the change. which at that point you could use actual matter to knock it out of the air much easier.

@John - it is not perfect - but it is plausible enough that it could work.
